# The supremum function for ideals is continuous

Tags: continuity, order-theory, supremum-and-infimum

Let $P$ be a dcpo, $Idl(P)$ be the set of ideals ordered by inclusion, and $f : Idl(P) \to P$ be the function defined by $f(I) = \bigvee I$.

**Question**: How to show that $f$ is Scott-continuous?

**My attempt**: Let $D$ be a directed set of ideals with a supremum $\hat I$. One needs to show that $\bigvee \hat I$ is the supremum of the set $\{\bigvee I \; \mid \; I \in D \}$. It is easy to show that $\bigvee \hat I$ is an upper bound, but I cannot figure out how to show that it is the least one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already concluded that $\bigvee \hat I$ is an upper bound of $\{\bigvee I : I \in D\}$.
Let $p$ be an arbitrary upper bound of $\{\bigvee I : I \in D\}$.
Then ${\downarrow}p$, the ideal generated by $p$, can easily be proven to be an upper bound of $D$, since $I \subseteq {\downarrow}p$ for each $I \in D$.
Thus $\hat I \subseteq {\downarrow}p$.

Comment: Why $I \subseteq {\downarrow}p$ for each $I \in D$?

Comment: If $p$ is an upper bound of $\{\bigvee I:i\in D\}$, then $\bigvee I\leq p$, for each $I\in D$, and if $\bigvee I\leq p$, then $$I\subseteq{\downarrow}p=\{x\in P:x\leq p\}.$$

Comment: @Bob In other words, if $\bigvee I \leq p$, then $a \leq p$ for each $a\in I$, and so $a\in {\downarrow}p$.